# Connecting the background of a list and a button

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm building a simple list to display various movies people have watched/not watched with two buttons at the bottom of the screen. When I created the list view I noticed that the background of the list and the buttons weren't connecting, leaving a bit of white space in between the two. My goal is to create a seamless background without whitespace between the two views. [Screenshot of the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw58H.png)

I tried 1) using a ZStack thinking it might cover everything behind both the list and the buttons, but the white space was still there, 2) removing the padding from the HStack holding the buttons thinking that was creating the space but it was still there after I removed the padding, and 3) embedding everything into a single stack thinking they just needed to be connected together. I've reverted back to my original code for the time being.

```
NavigationStack {
                List {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Test")
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Movie List")
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .background(Color(.gray))
                
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        ButtonView(buttonText: "Watched")
                        ButtonView(buttonText: "Not Watched")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.red))
                }
            }
        }

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Spacer(minLength: 0)` between `List` and button `Hstack`

```
NavigationStack {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Movie List")
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        .background(Color(.gray))
        
        //here
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
    
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                ButtonView(buttonText: "Watched")
                ButtonView(buttonText: "Not Watched")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color(.red))
        }
    }
}
```